# SQL Server 2012 Page Compression - Determine compression ratio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, compression

We're using SQL Server 2012 and have page compression turned on for a number of our larger tables. Is there a way we can determine the compression ratio we're getting? We'd like to be able to determine the benefits of compression.

Comment: Can you afford creating non-compressed copies of compressed tables? By doing that, you can easily find the uncompressed size. Sure, it's unelegant but could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`sp_estimate_data_compression_savings`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280574.aspx)?

It allows you to estimate the gain from compression BEFORE you compress the table, but it's quite accurate.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but that is just an estimate. I wanted the actual compression ratio, if it's available. And, besides, we've already enabled compression on many of our tables.

Comment: @Randy: You can use that stored procedure to do what you want: use the parameter `@data_compression = 'NONE'`.